# Kafka Connect Vertica Sink Connector Port Issue

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to use the Vertica Sink Connector. The database port we have is 443. The connector is expecting it to be between 1025 & 65535. Error I am getting is shown below. What can be done here ?

"message": "Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):\nInvalid value (443) must be between 1025 and 65535. for configuration vertica.port\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/{connectorType}/config/validate`"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Verica, but 443 is commonly an HTTPS port.

If you are truly using HTTPS, seems like you'll need a reverse proxy on another, higher port that redirects to the other one.

There is nothing you can do to fix the config validation if you don't have access to the source code.

Comment: Hi @cricket_007 , ok..thanks...running into issue with Splunk sink connector too. Will post another question.